# I am displaying the 2 icons on the based of checkbox click but if I selected >1 the checkbox no icon should be come

Tags: html, angular5

on the basis of I want to show the icon and if any one is selecting the multiple icon then icon should not come . In the above side 2 different icon will come

```html
<tr *ngFor="let data of mainData | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 10, currentPage: p } ; let i=index;">
  <td>
    <input class="custom-checkbox" (change)="onFilterChange($event,data)" type="checkbox" name="checkTest">
    <ng-container *ngIf="selectedAll.length > 1 ? isHide : !isHide">
      <ul class="list-inline icon-list" *ngIf="showIconForHide">
        <li class="list-inline-item">
          <i class="fa fa-eye-slash pointer hideClass hideIcons" [ngClass]="{'disabled': i == indexOfHide }" title="Hide visitor" (click)="hideStatus(data,i)"></i>
        </li>
        <li class="list-inline-item" *ngIf="!data.block_status">
          <i class="fa fa-ban pointer hideClass" title="Block notification" (click)="BlockVisitor(data)"></i>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </ng-container>
  </td>
  <td>
    {{data.ip_address |slice}}
  </td>
  <tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `this` keyword in HTML file, for accessing any
    property of component in template you don't need `this` variable .
    you can use it just by name.

Make sure that property should be `public`

Hope it will work.

Comment: thanks  it's my mistake to write this keyword but for kind your information both will work if you are using this or without this and it's not working.